# If Statements in Macros in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I originally had a macro written that would clear the specified cells in an excel sheet but I want to be able to only clear certain rows if I need to. This is what my macro looks like currently.

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo

If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("OK")
    Exit Sub
End If
    Range("A4:C30").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("G4:H30").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

I'm wanting to make it look something more like this though

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("OK")
    Exit Sub
End If
If I4 = 1 then
    Range("A4:C4","G4:H4").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

And then repeat that code for rows 5-30, when I run the code with multiple if statements it doesn't appear to do anything after the dialogue box pops up. Is there something else that I need to change?

Comment: `Range("A4:C30").Select ... Selection.ClearContents` is functionally equivalent to `Range("A4:C30").ClearContents`. There is almost never a good reason to use `Select` and `Selection` in VBA. See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/4996248). Also, the fact that you are using `I4` without declaring it suggests that you are not using `Option Explicit`. Failing to use that is a recipe for buggy code.

Comment: The `I4` in your code, since you haven't `Dim` it, it is a variable with no value. Try `[I4]` then.

Comment: should `I4` be `Range("I4")`?

Comment: Just `If Range("I4").Value = 1 Then Union(Range("A4:C4"),Range("G4:H4")).ClearContents` may do the job in a single line. Or making it really ugly: `If Range("I4").Value = 1 and response = vbYes Then Union(Range("A4:C4"),Range("G4:H4")).ClearContents` will replace both `If` blocks.

Comment: [I4] fixed the issue thank you for that. I think I don't have this part formatted properly though:    Range("A4:C4","G4:H4").Select because it is clearing cells D4 and E4, how would I fix that?

Comment: Thank you newacc2450 and JNevill! your suggestions made it do what I am wanting the macro to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through rows 4 -30:

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    Dim lRow As Long
    If MsgBox("Are you sure?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbYes Then
        For lRow = 4 To 30
            With ActiveSheet
                If .Cells(lRow, "I").Value = 1 Then
                    .Cells(lRow, "A").Resize(1, 3).ClearContents
                    .Cells(lRow, "G").Resize(1, 2).ClearContents
                End If
            End With
        Next lRow
    Else
        MsgBox "OK", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: No disrespect, but don't you think that using a variable named `lRow` in this instance could be confusing to noobs.

Comment: No. I don't. It describes exactly what we're looping through.

Answer (score 3):

No `.Select` required. Also, you do not need to test for `vbNo`. Just code for `vbYes` and `vbNo` does nothing by default

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbYes and Range("I4") = 1 Then
    Range("A4:C4","G4:H4").ClearContents
End If

End Sub
```

---

If you want to display a message box when they click `no` you can do something like so (although this seems redundant since the user already said `no`). If you place the `vbNo` at the end, you can avoid `Exit Sub` since this will happen during the natural flow

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()

response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)

If response = vbYes and Range("I4") = 1 Then
    Range("A4:C4","G4:H4").ClearContents
ElseIf response = vbNo
    Msgbox "OK"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could add a line `Option Explicit` to make sure all the variables in your code are well defined.

If you want to access a range, use a range object.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Rectangle1_Click()
    Dim response As Variant
    response = MsgBox("Are You Sure?", vbYesNo)

    If response = vbNo Then
        MsgBox ("OK")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim rngI As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Set rngI = Range("I4:I30")

    For Each cel In rngI
        If cel.value = 1 Then
            cel.Offset(0, -8).Resize(1, 3).ClearContents 'A:C
            cel.Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2).ClearContents 'G:H
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```